# How to trigger two different onPress listeners at the same time

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm kinda new to React and React Native, and I'm Working on a project, I need to trigger the onPress listeners of two elements that are one above the other.
[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQbVA.jpg):

ELEMENT1 is 'above' ELEMENT2 (Element 1 has an absolute position)

ELEMENT1  has an onPress prop that triggers a function, ELEMENT2 has another onPress prop that triggers another function, I want to tap on the element1 and execute both functions, and, when tapping just on the element2, just trigger the function of the element2.

Right now, when I tap on Element1, only the onPress function of the element1 is called. As I understand, React Native takes priorities when two overlapping elements are tapped at the same time.

I've tried using react native navigation v2 showing the element1 as an overlay
Also, i tried using the [Gesture Responder System](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system), but I can't achieve it.

A workaround is to call the function of the element 2 on the element1, but as my layout gets more complex, and more buttons are added, i would have to do that with every object, and that does not feels good, and is not clean, and if i need to do a change I will have to change every function of every tappable object.

If someone knows a way, or can point me/ lead me on some direction, I would be very grateful, thanks :)

Comment: Start from showing us your code, so we can see what did you tried and were is your issue. Also please, spend some time and take a tour here - https://stackoverflow.com/tour and check this useful info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please share code! But it seems like the solution is just to have a flag inside state that would be flipped when pressed so you can trigger both functions.